# Django Templates - Best Practice in Avoiding Repeating Code that Require Different For Loops?

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm creating a blog and have numerous pages that will display a list of articles. So, to avoid repeating that code, I'm trying to place it within a parent template that I can extend where needed.

The problem is I'll need a different for loop to display the article lists on each page/view. I figure the easiest approach would be to simply create blocks where I want the loop to start and close within the parent, then alter accordingly within each child.

However, Django doesn't allow you to close blocks that have an open for loop, despite closing the loop later in a different block.

My initial approach, in the parent, article_list.html:

```
                <div class="row">
                {% block loop_start %}
                {% endblock loop_start %}
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                    <div class="card">
                        <a class="img-card">
                        <img class="img-fluid"src="../../static/{{ post.featured_image }}" />
                      </a>.... etc
```

I know I have to fix my src code.

Extends to child as:

```
{% block loop_start %}
{% for post in recent_articles %}
{% endblock loop_start %}
```

However, that doesn't work as noted above.

I've also tried wrapping the entire code for the article list in a block, extending it and performing the following within the child:

```
    {% for post in recent_articles %}
    {% block.super article_list %}
    {% endblock article_list %}
    {% endfor %}
```

That doesn't work either. Again, producing the same error as a block is closing before the loop ends. I've also tried closing the loop in the parent which doesn't work either.

Is there an easier way of going about this that I'm missing? I could pass the same variable to each view then implement the loop in the parent, but that seems janky and limiting.

What's best practice here?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at a 'base.html' file. Take a look at this web-page: https://ultimatedjango.com/learn-django/lessons/create-the-project-base-template/

This will allow you to do {% extends 'base.html' %} all of which Django will handle.

Comment: I have a base html file that I'm extending, but there's no way I'm aware of to implement various different for loops on the same block. So I have my parent html code that displays a list of articles. In my child templates I need to iterate over that block based on what I'm trying to filter for that page. Some pages need multiple different filters. So I need to call the block and iterate accordingly. That being said, I don't believe I can have the loop in the parent. It needs to be in the child somehow.